# How to make sure that Google BigQuery consistently interprets a base64-encoded string as BYTES?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, encryption, google-bigquery

I'm working on a project where I write data to a Google BigQuery table. As part of the preprocessing step before writing to BigQuery, I encrypt part of the data using AES. I wrote a custom class to encrypt data:

```py
import base64
import hashlib
from typing import Generator, Union, List
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from app.settings import settings


encryption_key = hashlib.sha256(settings.QUERY_ENCRYPTION_KEY.encode()).digest()
cipher = AES.new(encryption_key, AES.MODE_ECB)

class AESEncryption:

    def __init__(self, data: Union[List[str], str]):

        self.data = data

    def encrypt(self) -> Union[List[str], str]:

        if isinstance(self.data, str):
            result_encrypted: str = self._encrypt_str()
        elif isinstance(self.data, list):
            result_encrypted: list = list(self._encrypt_iterable())
        else:
            raise TypeError("'data' should be either an str object "
                            + "or a list of str objects")

        return result_encrypted

    def _encrypt_iterable(self) -> Generator[str, None, None]:

        for d in self.data:
            ciphertext: bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(d.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size))
            d_encrypted: str = base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')
            yield d_encrypted

    def _encrypt_str(self) -> str:

        ciphertext: bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(self.data.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size))
        d_encrypted: str = base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')

        return d_encrypted
```

The encrypted data gets written to a column in a BigQuery table whose schema is BYTES. The writing process works fine in c. 85% of the cases; but sometimes it seems that BigQuery interprets the encrypted data as STRING instead of BYTES. This is the error message I get: "Field encrypted has changed type from BYTES to STRING" (again, in only c. 15% of the cases; mostly it works fine). I'm dazzled by the fact that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, especially since I put `autodetect` as `False` in my LOAD_JOB_CONFIG (see below). Anyone any ideas?

Below is the function I use to write data to BigQuery:

```py
    def load_data(self, data: List[dict], user_ref: bigquery.TableReference,
                  retries_per_iteration: int = 2, max_iterations: int = 3,
                  back_off_exp: float = 3.0):

        iterations = 0

        while iterations < max_iterations:
            try:
                iterations += 1
                job: LoadJob = bq_client.load_table_from_json(
                    json_rows=data, destination=user_ref,
                    num_retries=retries_per_iteration, job_config=bq_data_valid.LOAD_JOB_CONFIG
                )
                job.result()
                status = job.done()
                if status is True:
                    return
            except Forbidden as e:
                if iterations == max_iterations:
                    raise LoadError("Error while loading data") from e
                else:
                    back_off_time = iterations ** back_off_exp
                    time.sleep(back_off_time)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception("Error: %s", e)
                raise LoadError("Error while loading data") from e
```

Here is the LOAD_JOB_CONFIG variable:

```
LOAD_JOB_CONFIG = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=False,
    create_disposition="CREATE_NEVER",
    max_bad_records=0,
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND"
)
```

Finally, here are details of the relevant libraries (I'm using Python 3.9.12):
pycryptodome==3.17, google-api-core==2.11.0, google-api-python-client==2.81.0, google-cloud==0.34.0, google-cloud-bigquery==3.9.0

Comment: This more or less sounds a bug, and my hunch its one of the libraries. It would be good to create a testing dataset and code, and submit for a bug report either on support channel or via the public issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654